# minMaxLoc() opencv drama

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having a bit of trouble with minMaxLoc, When I try pass the Point in as reference to get the max_Loc im getting an error. After looking around I have found numerous examples of people using a double instead of a point but that is not the case here.

Here the code:

```
int ImageEvaluator::findPot()
{
    Point max_Loc;
    double max_Val;
    while (true)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {

            cv::Mat compResult;
            cv::matchTemplate(references[7], templates[7][j], compResult, 
                              CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
            cv::minMaxLoc(compResult, NULL, &max_Val, NULL, &max_Loc);

            if (max_Val > minAcceptableValue)
            {
                std::cout << "Stand up and shout how the **** did that just work" << std::endl;
                return joydivision;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error C2665 'cv::minMaxLoc': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

This is a small function that finds aload of numbers and I had it working great in python. As soon as I move over to c++ it has all gone downhill for me in the shape of the unwanted error above.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First I'd suggest normalizing the `compResult` and then trying to view it just to make sure the `matchTemplate()` result is as-expected. Do you get a proper linear index if you use [`minMaxIdx()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7622c466c628a75d9ed008b42250a73f) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi everyone after aload of head scratching it turns out that I was declaring my point incorrectly.

after changing:

```
Point max_Loc;
```

Into:

```
cv::Point min_Loc(0,0),max_Loc(0,0);
```

it seems to have worked. Thanks for all your help lol. :)